Formal Inverse of infinite-dimensional upper triangular matrix
If $A$ is an infinite-dimensional bounded upper triangular matrix in $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, i.e. $\langle Ae_n, e_m \rangle = 0$ for all $n > m$, where $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is the standard orthonormal basis of $l^2(\mathbb{Z})$, and assuming $\langle Ae_n, e_n \rangle \neq 0$ for all $n$. If there exists formal inverse upper triangular matrix $B$ such that $\langle Be_n, e_m \rangle = 0$ for all $n > m$, and  $\langle Be_n, e_m \rangle<\infty$ for all $n \leq m$(the bound may not uniform on $n$ and $m$), and satisfies $$\langle BAe_n, e_m \rangle:=\sum_k B_{nk}A_{km}=\langle e_n, e_m \rangle,$$ since the sum is finite, the definition is meaningful. Can we deduce that $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$?
If $A$ is a finite-dimensional matrix, the conclusion is obvious. Because if 0 is an eigenvalue, we cannot write the formal inverse matrix. In an infinity-dimensional space, I conjecture that $0$ may be the continuous spectrum or the residual spectrum of $A$, but I am unsure of how to show this.

No, we cannot. Here is a counterexample:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
\ddots\\
& 1\\
& & 1\\
& & & 1\\
& & & & 1 & -2\\
& & & & & \frac{1}{2} & -1\\
& & & & & & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{2}\\
& & & & & & & \frac{1}{8} & -\frac{1}{4}\\
& & & & & & & & \ddots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$B = \begin{pmatrix}
\ddots\\
& 1\\
& & 1\\
& & & 1\\
& & & & 1 & 4 & 16 & 64 & 256 & \cdots\\
& & & & & 2 & 8 & 32 & 128 & \cdots\\
& & & & & & 4 & 16 & 64 & \cdots\\
& & & & & & & 8 & 32 & \cdots\\
& & & & & & & & \ddots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$
It is not hard to check that $A$ is an infinite matrix that defines a bounded operator on $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$, and that $B$ is a formal inverse of $A$ in the sense that,
$$\sum_k A_{nk}B_{km} = \sum_k B_{nk}A_{km} = \delta_{nm}$$
However, $A$ does have $0$ as an eigenvalue. Indeed, if,
$$v = (\cdots, 0, 0, 0, 1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{1}{8}, \cdots) \in \ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$$
Then $Av = 0$.

Let $$Ae_n=e_n-2^{\text{sgn}(n)}e_{n-1}$$ where $\text{sgn}(0)=1.$ Then $A$ bounded and $\|A\|\le 2.$  The operator $A$ admits a formal inverse as a sum of the identity matrix  and a matrix with zero entries for any $(m,n)$ with $n-m\neq 1.$ Moreover the equation $Av=0$ admits a nonzero solution  $v_n=2^{-|n|}.$
In this example the diagonal coefficients  are all equal $1,$ hence they are bounded away from $0.$
